# Unable to find hdf5 libraries when building pycaffe

Tags: python, ubuntu, hdf5, caffe, pycaffe

When running

```
make pycaffe
```

We are ending up with missing `hdf5` libraries.

```
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:502: recipe for target 'python/caffe/_caffe.so' failed
make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

Note that every conceivable combination of these libraries has been installed on this `ubuntu 15.10` system.

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hdf5
hdf5-helpers                    install
libhdf5-10:amd64                install
libhdf5-cpp-10:amd64                install
libhdf5-dev                 install
libhdf5-mpi-dev                 install
libhdf5-mpich-10:amd64              install
libhdf5-mpich-dev               install
libhdf5-openmpi-10:amd64            install
libhdf5-openmpi-dev             install
libhdf5-serial-dev              install
```

Now I realize that is overkill .. but they were added one at a time - and then we retried the `make pycaffe` before adding another..  We just wanted to be sure *missing hdf5 libs* were not the core issue.

**Update** In response to the supplied answer from @jon

```
 dpkg -L libhdf5-dev | grep so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_cpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_fortran.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5hl_fortran.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_fortran.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so
```

And in the `Makefile.config`:

```
LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/opt/libsr $(PYTHON_LIB) 
   /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Does the caffe.bin demo work, which was created using 'make' command. Was that created successfully?

Comment: what's the outputs of `dpkg -L libhdf5-dev | grep so`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `dpkg -L libhdf5-dev | grep so` should output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5hl_fortran.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_fortran.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_cpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so
```

Make sure the path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (which contains `libhdf5.so` and `libhdf5_hl.so`) is in `Makefile.config`'s `LIBRARY_DIRS`

Comment: Updated OP: yes they are all in place.

Comment: @javadba you should add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial` according to your outputs